# Object properties of selected objects are null

Tags: linq-to-entities

I'm having trouble with Linq to entities framework.

Here is my code:

```cs
var activeScoreList = (from s in context.Score
                       join i in context.Import on s.import.importId equals i.importId
                       where i.isActive.Value == 1
                       select s).ToList();

foreach (Score s in activeScoreList)
{
    if (s.User.userId == loggedOnUserId) { // Here
        ...
    }
}
```

I have several `Score` objects in my database, and the foreign key `UserId` is `NOT NULL`.
However, there is **always an exception** at the `if` line. `User` property is always `null`.

I'm new to Linq, so I may have missed a configuration thing somewhere. Is this behaviour normal? Do I have to make a new query for each score to get the `User` object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit - You don't actually need a join statement. You can rewrite the query like so

```
var activeScoreList = (from s in context.Score.Include("User").Include("Import")
                       where s.Import.isActive.Value == 1
                       select s).ToList();
```

You need to load the User navigation property. So in your foreach statement you can call

```
s.UserReference.Load()
```

If you weren't using a `join` statement in your query you could use `context.Score.Include("User")`, however since you used a `join` it will ignore all `Include` statements

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about the Include() method!